# Why is my memory allocation method throwing Stack Overflow?

Tags: c#, .net

I store all of my profiles into a profileCache, which eats up a ton of memory within the Large Object Heap. Therefore, I have implemented a method to help delete unused cache. The problem is the method doesn't seem to be clearing the cache correctly and is throwing a stack overflow error. Here is the two methods I have implemented.

```
private static void OnScavengeProfileCache(object data)
{
    // loop until the runtime is shutting down
    while(HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason == ApplicationShutdownReason.None)
    {
        // NOTE: Right now we only do the scavenge when traffic is temporarily low,
        // to try to amortize the overhead of scavenging the cache into a low utilization period.
        // We also only scavenge if the process memory usage is very high.
        if (s_timerNoRequests.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 10000)
        {
            // We dont want to scavenge under lock to avoid slowing down requests,
            // so we get the list of keys under lock and then incrementally scan them
            IEnumerable<string> profileKeys = null;
            lock (s_profileCache)
            {
                 profileKeys = s_profileCache.Keys.ToList();
            }

            ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(profileKeys.GetEnumerator());
        }

        // wait for a bit
        Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

My method is constantly scanning traffic, and when traffic is low, it collects all of my profiles and stores them into an IEnumerable called profileKeys. I then invoke this method to delete unused keys -

```
private static void ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(IEnumerator<string> profileKeys)
{
    if (s_thisProcess.PrivateMemorySize64 >= (200 * 1024 * 1024) ) // 3Gb at least
    {
        int numProcessed = 0;
        while(profileKeys.MoveNext())
        {
            var key = profileKeys.Current;
            Profile profile = null;
            if (s_profileCache.TryGetValue(key, out profile))
            {
                // safely check/remove under lock, its fast but makes sure we dont blow away someone currently being addded
                lock (s_profileCache)
                {
                    if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(profile.CreateTime).TotalMinutes > 5)
                    {
                        // can clear it out
                        s_profileCache.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (++numProcessed >= 5)
            {
                // stop this scan and check memory again
                break;
            }

        }
            // Check again to see if we freed up memory, if not continue scanning the profiles?
            ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(profileKeys);
    }
}
```

The method is not clearing up memory and is throwing a stack overflow error with this trace:

```
192. ProfileHelper.ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(
193. ProfileHelper.ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(
194. ProfileHelper.ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(
195. ProfileHelper.ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(
196. ProfileHelper.OnScavengeProfileCache(...)
197. ExecutionContext.RunInternal(...)
198. ExecutionContext.Run(...)
199. IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem(...)
200. ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch(...)
```

EDIT:

So would this be a possible solution to remove unused profile keys and clear LOH...

```
private static void ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(IEnumerator<string> profileKeys)
{
    if (s_thisProcess.PrivateMemorySize64 >= (200 * 1024 * 1024) ) // 3Gb at least
    {
        int numProcessed = 0;
        while(profileKeys.MoveNext())
        {
            var key = profileKeys.Current;
            Profile profile = null;
            if (s_profileCache.TryGetValue(key, out profile))
            {
                // safely check/remove under lock, its fast but makes sure we dont blow away someone currently being addded
                lock (s_profileCache)
                {
                    if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(profile.CreateTime).TotalMinutes > 5)
                    {
                        // can clear it out
                        s_profileCache.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (++numProcessed >= 5)
            {
                // stop this scan and check memory again
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    GC.Collect;
}
```

Comment: `ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(profileKeys)` is a recursive call that just repasses seemingly unchanged keys. It seems like that would just loop until it crashes.

Comment: Finally, a "Stack Overflow" question about stack overflow

Comment: Wouldn't I be deleting the keys by calling the profileCache.remove(key) call? @Carcigenicate

Comment: @Carcigenicate - I think the intention is that the recursion will be interrupted by the free-space check at the top of the method. Assuming the method does what its supposed to of course...

Comment: You have no exit condition for your ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental.

Comment: @Matt I'll admit that I don't know c#, but `s_profileCache` doesn't seem to have anything to do with `profileKeys`

Comment: So should I have my OnScavengeProfileCache constantly scan and my ScavengeProfileCache method have an exit... correct?

Comment: @Matt Removing the keys doesn't automatically free memory - the garbage collector will do so at the next sweep. You could force a garbage collection by using [GC.Collect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Have you considered using `MemoryCache` instead of trying to build cache/policy system yourself?

Comment: I updated the original post, would this be a sufficient solution to removing old profile keys and collecting unused LOH?

Comment: Ditching the recursion is an important step. Forcing a GC - well ... not always a good idea. My thought was if those cache lines are so big - why not avoid them in the first place? 1. Can you have a max size of the cache and new entries replace the oldest ones on entry? 2. Do you really need _all_ of the data cached?  3. Is the problem gone without the recursion and without GC.Collect?

Comment: Aside from the very wise remark that you should first try the wheel that's already been invented (`MemoryCache`), do note that `GC.Collect()` isn't going to do *anything* about the LOH by default. That requires setting [`GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode) first. That's assuming, of course, that the LOH really is your problem, and not just the heap in general. And it's assuming that `.Remove()` actually does anything about it (`Dictionary.Remove` does not shrink the underlying collections).

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they
  belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to
  you, it might still be  beneficial to someone in the future. If there
  is any confidential information revealed in your post, please edit it
  out with dummy data, and flag for the history to be redacted.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code is suffering of a problem known as **Infinite Recursion**.

You are calling method `ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental`, which in turn calls itself internally. At some point, you call into it enough times that you run out of **stack**, causing an **overflow**.

Either your condition is not being met before you run out of stack, or your condition is never met at all. Debugging should show you why.

You can read more on the subject [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Answer (score 1):

There is no exit from SaveProfileCacheIncremental.

It does its stuff and then calls itself. It then does its stuff and calls itself. It then does its stuff and calls itself. It then does its stuff and calls itself. It then does its stuff and calls itself.

After a while it uses all the stack space and the process crashes.